# Correct usage of said to

Tags: usage

Is the following sentence correct?

> A day after the encounter with Maoists in Chhattisgarh’s Sukma, as many as 21 security personnel are **said to missing**.

I think it should be **are said to be missing**.

I asked this question because this sentence is in a very prestigious newspaper, so I thought I might be wrong?

Comment: Please link to the source if possible, or at least mention the name of the newspaper if not.

Comment: If, your source is https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/other-states/sukma-encounter-21-security-personnel-missing-says-chhattisgarh-dgp/article34236487.ece  then the grammar error has already been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It's not grammatical, you are right. The correct phrasing should have been

> 21 security personnel are said **to be missing**

or simply

> 21 security personnel are **missing**

While googling, I came across a different phrasing of the same sentence, it went

> <strike>21 security personnel are said to be lacking.</strike>

which is equally unacceptable.